# Circular dependency issue while exporting from single file using babel-module-resolver

Tags: react-native, circular-dependency, madge

I was working on a react native project and while perfoming hot reloading app goes into cyclic recursion resulting in maximum call stack exceeded. More details of this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7288.)

From here I realised that there is something wrong and circular dependencies are getting created.

I decided to give [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madg) a try and see whats going on in the project. After running the command I saw quite a number of circular dependencies.

Now since my project is quite huge debugging that was quite a task so I created a small version of my project containing a single folder.

I created a utils folder in which I have 4 files: -

1. utils/index.js
2. utils/device-helper.js
3. utils/init.js
4. index.js

For imports I am using `babel-module-resolver`

**utils/init.js**

```
import {deviceInfo} from "utils";

export const init = () => {
  // initialising app and calling backend API with device info
};
```

**utils/device-helper.js**

```
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";

const API_LEVEL = "v0";

export const deviceInfo = () => {
  try {
    return Object.assign({}, {
      apiLevel: API_LEVEL,
      deviceId: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
      device: DeviceInfo.getDeviceName(),
      model: DeviceInfo.getModel(),
      osVersion: DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion(),
      product: DeviceInfo.getBrand(),
      country: DeviceInfo.getDeviceCountry(),
      appVersion: DeviceInfo.getVersion(),
      manufacturer: DeviceInfo.getManufacturer(),
      userAgent: DeviceInfo.getUserAgent(),
      buildNumber: DeviceInfo.getBuildNumber(),
      bundleId: DeviceInfo.getBundleId()
    });
  } catch (e) {
    //  TODO: Report to Bugsnag
    return {};
  }
};
```

**utils/index.js**

```
export * from "./init";
export * from "./device-info-helper";
```

**index.js**

```
export * from "./utils";
```

After running `madge` command I get following :-

```
tests-MBP:madge-test harkirat$ madge --circular  index.js
Processed 4 files (684ms)

✖ Found 1 circular dependency!

1) utils/index.js > utils/init.js
```

However, if i change utils/init.js to following it works:-

**utils/init.js**

```
import {deviceInfo} from "./device-helpers";


export const init = () => {
  // initialising app and calling backend API with device info
};
```

I am not able to understand the cause of this circular dependency. Can someone please help?

[Here](https://github.com/jinxac/madge-babel-module) is link to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `.babelrc` in the repo, but here is what I think:

1. In `utils/init.js` you import using:

`import {deviceInfo} from "utils";`

That is same as:

`import {deviceInfo} from "./utils/index";`

2. In `utils/index.js` you do a `export * from "./init"`. This `export from` basically first imports all the contents of `./utils/init` and the reexports it.

So:

- `utils/init.js` imports from `./utils/index`
- `./utils/index.js` imports from `./utils/init`

There is your circular dependency.